Не запускается файл с кодом
Устаналивал VS Code и сопутствующие дополнения к нему по инструкции яндекс-лицея, при попытке запуска кода через команду go run test.go выдает ошибку:
go : Имя "go" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность
написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.


Сам компилятор go установлен?

а что это такое и как это установить?) недавно так скажем вошел в мир цифровой

компилятор установлен..

@ConnorMcDuff, компилятор - это то, что превращает исходный код в exe файл (если сильно упростить). Какой у вас редактор кода и какие в нем расширения установлены - вообще не важно. Нужно чтобы компилятор был, а в чем вы пишете код - без разницы. Если установлен, значит не прописан в переменную окружения PATH.

Перейдите по этой ссылке на официальный сайт Go и выполните инструкцию по установке. Далее может потребоваться заново открыть терминал или перезагрузить компьютер. После этого "go" должно автоматически распознавать в системе.
Для проверки в переменных окружения можно поискать GOPATH и GOROOT

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
